# Can be method from other class be ever inlined?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, asp.net-4.0, .net-4.5

Imagine you have class A which has code which runs as method M. And there is class B which needs to signal A that it is time to run M.

Normally you will fire an event. However there are few ways to do it. Fire an event, call Action or call M as public method. ie:

```
b.OnMEvent(this, null);
b.MAction();
a.M();
```

**Is there any chance that any of these (or other) ways to call other calss method be inlined in run-time?**

**Is it possible to achieve in .NET 4.5 with aggressive inlining?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of the .NET JIT does not inline delegate calls. Events are using delegates as a mechanism for invocation so event invocations won't be inlined either.

Inlining a delegate is hard because the target is not necessarily known at compile time. There are mitigating techniques but the current JIT does not implement any of them.

Delegate invocations are fast enough in most cases, though.

Comment: thank you. not even 4.5? PS yes I know they are fast but when you count every microsecond it worth to check.. yes I know C++ can be faster.... but not always. c# works for me just fine :)

Comment: I don't know but I doubt it. The .NET JIT is not good. Apparently, it does not receive much investment. Years ago it was even known to be buggy (security bugs among others).